# Total $5$ digit numbers that can be formed where the numbers don't go over a given number

Tags: combinatorics

We are given a $5$ digit number ($x$) and we need to find all the $5$ digit numbers less than $x$ where there are exactly $4$ repetitions of a particular digit.

Eg. $10000, 20000, 11112, 22221, 11211,\ldots$ up to $x$.

Between $10000$ and $20000$ (inclusive), there are $46$ such numbers.

Comment: Is your goal to find a formula that depends on $x$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Correct